# Access windows 10 without knowing password

Tags: windows-10

Basically i want to enter my laptop windows 10 without knowing password.i could do it on windows 7 by changing the utilman file to cmd.then changing password in cmd.how to do it in windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

You need your password to get into Windows. If it is a Microsoft Account (a number of people use this), go to the Microsoft Account Login site and reset your password.

If it is a local account, you should be able to change the password with some of the bootable tools. You can try PogoStick and there are others. This is only for a Local Account and not the Microsoft Account.

https://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/

Windows 10 has seriously increased security to prevent unauthorized entry into computers.

Comment: Is it possible without bootable tools?like in windows 7?

Comment: Only with a local account.  Also the tool you pick must be Windows 10 compatible.

Comment: Yes it is a local account

Comment: Try Pogo Stick and look at another tool that says it will work on a Windows 10 machine.

Comment: In windows 7 you don't need bootable tools.you can do it by cmd .that is what i wanted to know

Comment: Windows 10 is nothing whatever like Windows 7. Windows 7 is gone.

Comment: Btw i wanted to know if there is a way to find the password without changing it

Comment: No. You must change the password as described. You would need to hack into the system to find the password and it is now much more difficult than it ever used to be. Windows 10 has seriously increased security.

Comment: You could suggest me a link or something.

Comment: I did provide a link for Pogo Stick above.

Comment: For finding the password thing

Comment: Here is a list to choose from.  Brute forcing can take days or longer to crack a password.  https://www.itpro.co.uk/security/34616/the-top-ten-password-cracking-techniques-used-by-hackers